# Loading a local ASP.NET app takes forever

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp.net

I'm working on a large ASP.NET application on my local machine (IIS7, local SQL Server 2014, ASP.NET 4.6.2).

Since a few days, this application usually loads ok (kind of) after a clean/build operation, but starts taking forever (and thus getting frequent timeouts) after a few clicks or after a standard build.

I wasn't able to find what is happening, the CPU is mostly idle, SQL server is reactive (and works ok from SSMS), IIS doesn't have any hanging request except for the current one.

Of course, the same code executed on another computer (same model) with the same configuration (IIS and SQL Server versions, same database) works correctly.

Sorry I don't have any more information to provide, I'm a little clueless here.

Is there some stuff I can check ?

Please ask for more information if needed.

Comment: Have you tried to debug or profile it?

Comment: I didn't profile it, but I debug it regularly, but this doesn't help, the behavior is the same. As said, the code is functional, and acceptably efficient on another identical platform.

Comment: Can you debug it on this IIS, pause it, and check thread stacks to find where exactly thread stopped?

Comment: It hangs on a huge (and certainly for from optimal) SQL query. What remains to find out is why this query doesn't almays take ages on the same dataset, but I guess I can work from there. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

when you clean you aplication you also remove cache files, its normal take some time to your application go faster again.
look at you pool on IIS,go on Advanced Configurations > Start Mode : AlwaysRunning